# Matplotlib graph appearing as a Python list type

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, graph, types

The following code produces a graph:

```
import matplotlib
gr = matplotlib.pyplot.plot([1,2,3])
```

[image]

Now, if I check the type of this seemingly graph object:

```
type(gr)
```

The output is:

```
list
```

I was expecting it to be some sort of matplotlib graph object, but this comes to be a native Python list. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well what is returned is a list of the lines that are plotted not the graph object itself, see the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=.plot#matplotlib.pyplot.plot)

> Return value is a list of lines that were added.

in my case I see this as the object:

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xb2f83c8>]
```

the type is a `list` and the contents are a `Line2D` object:

```
In [141]:

for e in l:
    print(e)
Line2D(_line0)
```

The contents of the `Line2D` are the lines added to the plot:

```
In [146]:

l[0].get_data()
Out[146]:
(array([ 0.,  1.,  2.]), array([1, 2, 3]))
```

**EDIT**

If you want to access the `Figure` for saving, I personally write like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.Figure() #  do something with Figure here
```

Comment: So how do I go about saving a figure? `list[0].get_figure()` or is there  any more elegant way?

Comment: Normally people do this `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt plt.plot([1,2,3])` you can then access the figure using `plt.Figure()`

Answer (score 1):

From the matplotlib [documents](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot), the plot function,

> Return value is a list of lines that were added.

Each of the list items themselves are `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` types, as perhaps would be expected.